# php catch post proper way

Tags: php, security, sql-injection

In server side php how to catch post from view then do business logic, should I use below example 2- write down every post key, if use 1- is there any secure problem could happen?

1-

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
  // do something use $_POST['..']
} else {
  // denied
}
```

2-

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['password_confirm']) ) {
  // do something
} else {
  // denied
}
```

3-

```
if ($_POST) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure the function(s)/method(s) that are using these post values are protected against SQL Injection, and that they do basic check on their input arguments, and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

For sql prevention you have two option

- Escaping the single quotes
- Prepared statements

For example you can use to escape you can use "mysql_real_escape_string" function

```
 if (isset($_POST)) {
  $some_key = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST{'some_key'});
 } else {
 // denied
  }
```

for prepared statements you should use mysqli instead od mysql, and then should perform db operations like

```
     if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT priv FROM testUsers WHERE username=?
   AND password=?")) {


      $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $_POST['user_key'], $_POST['pass_key']);


      $stmt -> execute();}
```